# Service is not running in background in nougat

Tags: android

My app's `location update service` not displaying in list in nougat device. But it display in lower devices.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is due to background execution Limit in android 7.0,you have to use either job scheduler or Foreground service for fetching location in the background.refer [Android 7.0 platform changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html)

Comment: use of foreground service, always show notification. Give me the example of job scheduler.

Comment: @vivekmodi there is no such direct example available I will post it if I  found it

Comment: @vivekmodi refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752293/location-updates-using-jobscheduler-api/43752497#43752497